# Can't run web app after importing in Eclipse

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I was working on this web application at the office, and I wanted to do some stuff from home as well so I set up the environment on my home pc.

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.37 and I imported the project with "Import existing project" in Eclipse.
But as soon as I want to run it I get this error:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/IRSimWebApp]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/IRSimWebApp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [addTreeServlet] and [org.sven.addTreeServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/addTreeServlet] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2412)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2125)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2080)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

Feb 23, 2013 2:06:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

Feb 23, 2013 2:06:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

I set up the environment at the office as well, like 3 months ago. So I'm pretty sure I did the same steps now at home.

I also noticed this exception here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [addTreeServlet] and [org.sven.addTreeServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/addTreeServlet] which is not permitted
```

But I don't know why there would be two servlets now. There's only one in the architecture and there's also only one mapping in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addTreeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>addTreeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addTreeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addTreeServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you please attach a project architecture screenshot ??

Comment: you mean something like this? http://postimage.org/image/ree4gnsm3/

Answer (score 0):

Your web.xml mapping should be like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addTreeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.sven.addTreeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addTreeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addTreeServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi, I resolved the problem but then another appeared. I've got some upload functionality and usually it uploads to the path where the servlet is executed: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\IRSimWebApp but now on the new machine it uploads to C:\Users\Sven\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IRSimWebApp\ and this causes some problems in the later execution. Where can I change the path from where the web app is executed?

Comment: Update: thats not what caused the error apparently.. it is a NumberFormatException that gets thrown because the program was developed on an American system and I now wanna run it on a German one.. Any ideas on that? java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string "0,101" at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString java.lang.Float.valueOf()

Comment: If you see the full stackTrace you can find from where its throwing .Whats happening there is some where its coming as "0,101"in between comma is there so its throwing exception ..you have to know the line number from stack trace from where the exception is throwing .Please accept the answer if its use full ,And that number format exception   question is out of topic for this question you can ask another question with that stack trace or give me the full stack trace,If possible I can help you out .